# Tool to easily block Internet access completely for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, networking, blocking

I would like to block Internet access for my own machine. This is so that no apps can talk to the outside in the time frame I want it to. I know a firewall can do this but I don't want to install one. I don't want to use the included one. I know also I can change the gateway but that involves several clicks. I am looking for a system tray software or simple desktop app to toggle the access. On/Off with a single click.

Comment: Do you still need _local_ network connectivity, or would it work to disable your network access completely?

Comment: I don't need local connectivity.

Answer (score 5):

You don't specify whether you need local connectivity as well.  If you don't, the so-simple-someone-could-easily-overlook-it, 100% foolproof solution is to just *unplug the network cable*.

Comment: If it's a laptop or netbook, those tend to have a button to turn off disable wifi connection

Comment: I am not using wifi. Unplugging works but I don't want to do that. I should have added this to the options I don't want to use.

Comment: @Tony - So basically, you don't want to do anything easy?  Have it your way, I guess.  Maybe you'll luck out and somebody will find an app that does nothing but enable and disable the network adapter for you with a single click, but I've never seen such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 it's just

```
ipconfig /release
```

and

```
ipconfig /renew
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two batch files, one to release your IP address and one to renew your IP address. Then create a shortcut to each of them in your Quick Launch toolbar.

To disconnect:

```
ipconfig /release
```

To connect:

```
ipconfig /renew
```